# Why is this Spring Aspect not printing as it should with method parameter?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspects

> Let me first foremention, the problem I'm facing is with the 
> **`interceptThoughts(String thoughts)`** 
> method, from the first code block, not printing

I'm running a tutorial from *Spring in Action*. There's a `Magician` class that `implements MindReader` interface with methods `interceptThoughts(String thoughts)` and `getThoughts()`

```
@Aspect
public class Magician implements MindReader {

    private String thoughts;

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.underdogdevs.myspringaspectj." 
            + "Thinker.thinkOfSomething(String)) && args(thoughts)")
    public void thinking(String thoughts) {
    }

    @Override
    @Before("thinking(thoughts)") 
    public void interceptThoughts(String thoughts) {
        System.out.println("Intercepting volunteer's thoughts : " + thoughts);  
        this.thoughts = thoughts;
    }

    @Override
    public String getThoughts() {
        return thoughts;
    }
}
```

The aspect is supposed to read the mind of a `Volunteer` that `implements Thinker` interface, with method `thinkOfSomething(String thoughts)`

```
public class Volunteer implements Thinker {

    private String thoughts;

    @Override
    public void thinkOfSomething(String thoughts) {
        this.thoughts = thoughts;
        System.out.println("Something");
    }

    public String getThoughts() {
        return thoughts;
    }
}
```

I have my java `BeanConfig` with the `Magician` and the `Volunteer`

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public MindReader magician() {
        return new Magician();
    }

    @Bean
    public Thinker volunteer() {
        return new Volunteer();
    }  
}
```

**And I'm trying to run it to get the `Magician` method to print the line in the `interceptThoughts` method**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-idol.xml");

        System.out.println();
        Thinker volunteer = (Thinker)context.getBean("volunteer");
        volunteer.thinkOfSomething("This is what I'm thinking");
    }
}
```

---

- NO Eorrrs
- NO Exceptions
- The package is correct in the `@Pointcut(execution(` in the `Magician` aspect
- I have these two items in my Spring config xml

  ```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.underdogdevs.myspringaspectj" />
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
  ```

> The problem is the `@Before` from the `Magician` aspect isn't printing as it should. **Am I missing something here? Why is it not printing? I have other aspect methods that take no arguments and run just fine. Am I not passing the parameter value correctly?**

Comment: this may be a wild guess because your aspects seem correct to me; did you try annotating Volunteer and Magician as `@Component`s ? or placing the pointcut inside the @Before annotation?

Comment: !guido I just tried it, but it doesn't work. I figured that's what _this_ `<context:component-scan.../>` is for, to scan for the bean within the context, without acutally specifying `@Component`

Comment: well, actually `context:component-scan` is for scanning the classes *in search for* @Component annotations (and @Service, @Controller, ...and also @Configuration which is meta-annotated with @Component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public Magician magician() {
        return new Magician();
    }
...
```

I don't know whether it is in Spring's docs, but it's clear that when Spring analizes return type of `magician()` and when it is `MindReader` Spring cannot see any annotation on it.

Comment: can you please explain why this works? Do all aspect beans need to be declared this way, with the concrete class?

Answer (score 2):

Evgeniy has a solution, I just want to explain what happens.

When you specify

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

or annotate a `@Configuration` class (which you load) with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, Spring registers a [`AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/annotation/AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.html) which is a `BeanPostProcessor` that

> processes all AspectJ annotation aspects in the current application
>   context, as well as Spring Advisors. Any AspectJ annotated classes
>   will automatically be recognized, and their advice applied if Spring
>   AOP's  proxy-based model is capable of applying it.

One step of this process includes finding candidate Advisors. It does so by scanning your bean definitions and checking the bean types. This happens before any beans have been created and therefore the process can only rely on what has been declared. It's guessing.

With `<bean>` declarations, it wouldn't usually be a problem because you would specifically declare the bean's class in the `class` attribute.

With `@Bean` methods however, you can specify an interface instead. Note that `<bean>` and `@Bean` declarations could both fail if you were using a factory method to generate the bean.

So the `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` looks at all the bean definitions in the context and guesses their type. With a `@Bean` declaration, it looks at the method's return type.

In your case, the return type will be `MindReader` which is not a candidate since it does not have an `@Aspect` annotation. As such, no advice (no proxies) will be applied and you won't see the behavior you were expecting.

Possible solutions:

- [Evgeniy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21201641/438154) to change the return type and therefore make it obvious to Spring what the bean type is
- Get rid of your `@Bean` definition, annotate your `Magician` class with `@Component`, and have its package be `component-scan`ned. Because the type is obviously the annotated class, Spring will be able to tell that it's also annotated with `@Aspect`.

---

Note that are many other `BeanPostProcessor` implementations that guess the type of the bean. You have to be aware at which point (before or after initialization) processing happens.

Comment: Thanks +3 for that one ;)